# Type Conversion in Persisted Computed Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, calculated-columns

I'm working with 2 related tables in a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 environment which are connected via a GUID. In one table, the field has the type `varchar(50)`, the other one is properly types as `uniqueidentifier`. This is obviously bad but I can't change this now because it's given by a legacy piece of software.

The conversion SQL Server needs to perform at each inner join makes queries running terribly slow, since I can't use indices at all. I tried adding a Computed Column, which is persisted, to get the ID stored as a `uniqueidentifer`. This way I could add an index to get it running much faster probably. I failed.

Does anybody know if I can store an explicitly converted value in a computer column. If I can, what's the formula to use here?

Cheers,
Matthias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
CREATE TABLE t_uuid (charid VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, uuid AS CAST(charid AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER))

CREATE INDEX IX_uuid_uuid ON t_uuid (uuid)

INSERT
INTO    t_uuid (charid)
VALUES  (NEWID())

SELECT  *
FROM    t_uuid
```

Comment: Thank you, works great. Query takes 4sec instead of half an hour now. :)

Answer (score 1):

CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, your_varchar_here)

Comment: Works well. Management Studio says `Error validating the formula for column 'MyColumn'.`, but nevertheless saves the changes and it works. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how often you need to make the conversion for joining,  I'd use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) to convert the data type(s).  It is constructed faster than an inline view (next best temporary option).  In either case, you'd expose value as the correct data type in a result column from the CTE/inline view so you can JOIN on to it.  CTE Example:

```
WITH example AS (
   SELECT t.guid
          CONVERT(UniqueIdentifier, t.guid) 'cguid'
     FROM TABLE t)
SELECT t.*
  FROM TABLE t
  JOIN example e ON e.cguid = t.guid
```

Inline view example:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM TABLE t
  JOIN (SELECT t.guid
               CONVERT(UniqueIdentifier, t.guid) 'cguid'
          FROM TABLE t) e ON e.cguid = t.guid
```

It's not going to get around that the index for guid (assuming one does) won't be used, but it's also not a good habit to be performing data type conversion in the WHERE clause.